# Definite integral of 1/polynomial in cos\phi

Tags: calculus, integration

Does the following integral have an analytical solution?
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{{\rm d}\phi}{a+b \cos\phi + c \cos^2 \phi}
$$

Comment: A general solution is not guaranteed. I can think of a few special cases. For example, $b=c=0$ with $a \neq 0$. You could also have a case of $b=0, a = -c$  because that would mean $a+c\cos^2(\phi) = -c(1-\cos^2(\phi)) = -c\sin^2(\phi)$.

Comment: An example of some nice results you may obtain: $$ 
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{{\rm d}\phi}{1+\cos\phi +  \cos^2 \phi}=\frac{2\pi}{3} \sqrt{3+2 \sqrt{3}} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Obviusly there are some constraints since the integrand function may have a singularity along the integration range. Anyway, assuming that the integrand function is continuous over $[0,2\pi]$, we have:

$$ I = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{a+b\cos\theta+c\cos^2\theta}=4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)\left(a+b\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+c\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2\right)} $$

or:

$$ I = 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{a(1+t^2)^2+b(1-t^4)+c(1-t^2)^2}\,dt $$
that can be computed through the residue theorem (and a little patience).

Answer (score 0):

> *Does the following integral have an analytical solution?*

Of course it does. $($In fact, all integrals of rational functions of trigononetric functions do$)$. Just use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution), and then apply [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).